# Preventing file handle inheritance in multiprocessing lib

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, handle

Using multiprocessing on windows it appears that any open file handles are inherited by spawned processes.  This has the unpleasant side effect of locking them.

I'm interested in either:
1) Preventing the inheritance
2) A way to release the file from the spawned process

Consider the following code which works fine on OSX, but crashes on windows at os.rename

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

kFileA = "a.txt"
kFileB = "b.txt"

def emptyProcess():
    while 1:
        pass

def main():
    # Open a file and write a message
    testFile = open(kFileA, 'a')
    testFile.write("Message One\n")

    # Spawn a process
    p = Process(target=emptyProcess)
    p.start()

    # Close the file
    testFile.close()

    # This will crash
    # WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file
    #               because it is being used by another process
    os.rename(kFileA, kFileB)

    testFile = open(kFileA, 'a')
    testFile.write("Message Two\n")
    testFile.close()

    p.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

The `fileno()` method returns the file number as assigned by the runtime library. Given the file number, you can then call `msvcrt.get_osfhandle()` to get the Win32 file handle. Use this handle in the call to `SetHandleInformation`. So something like the following may work:

```
win32api.SetHandleInformation(
    msvcrt.get_osfhandle(testFile.fileno()),
    win32api.HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,
    0)
```

I'm not certain of the exact usage of the `win32api` module, but this should help bridge the gap between a Python file object and a Win32 handle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the *multiprocessing* module, but with the [*subprocess*](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module you can instruct it to not inherit any file descriptors:

> If close_fds is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be closed before the child process is executed. (Unix only). Or, on Windows, if close_fds is true then no handles will be inherited by the child process. Note that on Windows, you cannot set close_fds to true and also redirect the standard handles by setting stdin, stdout or stderr.

Alternatively you could close all file descriptors in your child process with [os.closerange](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.closerange)

> Close all file descriptors from fd_low (inclusive) to fd_high (exclusive), ignoring errors. Availability: Unix, Windows.

Comment: I'm aware of the subprocess flag, but I'm specifically asking about the multiprocessing module.  Additionally, if we have another pipe or file we do want to inherit the close_fds flag is a little heavy handed.

Comment: @vilalian In the case where you want to keep inherited file descriptor(s), you would need to pass this information to the subprocess so that it knows which file descriptor(s) not to close. There's no other way.

Comment: note: default is `subprocess.Popen(close_fds=True)` so by default, the fds are not inherited

Answer (score 0):

After you open a file handle, you can use the SetHandleInformation() function to remove the `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` flag.

Comment: How does one obtain the file handle from something created with open(), not os.open()?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue when using a rotating log and multiprocessing. When the parent process tries to rotate the log, it fails with a

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

based on some of the other answers, the following is a working solution in python 2.7 to prevent log file handlers from been inherited

```
fd = logging.getLogger().handlers[0].stream.fileno() # The log handler file descriptor
fh = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(fd) # The actual windows handler
win32api.SetHandleInformation(fh, win32con.HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) # Disable inheritance
```

Please note this issue was somewhat address in python 3.4. for more info see 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/

Answer (score 0):

use `os.set_inheritable` check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#fd-inheritance) for more details